# How do we register our child as a Portugese national?

Tags: marriage, passport, eu-spouses, portugal

I have been married to an EU national of Portugal. We got married in a non-EU country, whereas I am not from the EU and on a spouse visa in the UK. Now we have a son who is two years old. While applying for his Portugese passport (as his mother is a Portugese), we were told that our marriage needs to be registered in the Portugese embassy, after which the child will be registered as a Portugese national.

How do I register my marriage and child in Portugal, as their websites are all in their language and translation doesn't help?

Comment: Couldn't your wife translate the websites for you? You say translation doesn't hellp, but translation sounds like exactly what you need. What country were you married in?

Comment: @ouflak no she cannot, the google translation doesn't make sense sometimes. We were married in Pakistan

Answer (score 2):

I’m Portuguese and Brazilian. My wife is Brazilian. We live in Luxembourg and we are married only in Brazil.
We had a child here this year and I registered him as portuguese at the embassy.

If one of the parents is portuguese, it’s enough to register a child. Your wife should go to the embassy with her documents and child birth certificate from your country, maybe with a sworn translation to portuguese. Here we didn’t need it because Luxembourg emits on an European standard format.

Regarding marriage transcription (something I’m about to do), what you will need is a marriage certificate, yours birth certificate, your wife Portugal’s id. Both certificates must follow a sworn translation to portuguese. They must also be recent (<6 months emission date).

Comment: Thanks, It has been a while since I been on this website and now in full motion to register our son, since I mentioned the portuguese embassy in UK won't register our marriage as they said "you need to go to Portugal to register, not here coz of fake marriages", that is first step of registering our son. Should I travel with my wife or she can go with her uncle as only he speaks portuguese

Comment: I would advise you to go together, as the embassy/consulate may ask about you or for a signature. In my case, my wife wasn't present (she just had gave birth at the time) but they asked for her signature on a document, so I had to take the document to her and collect the signature first.

Comment: upon investigation, I found that it is the marriage that needs to be registered in Portugal and I have no idea what to do, never been there and what my wife and ppl tell me, if u can't speak Portuguese they won't entertain you and UK cannot register marriages as some of the marriages are paperwork so they cannot authenticate,